# Groups of matrices in which all elements have all eigenvalues equal in modulus

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

I am writing a research article in which I need to use the following fact: if $G$ is a subgroup of $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$ which is irreducible in the sense that no proper nontrivial subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is preserved by all elements of $G$, and if every element of $G$ has all eigenvalues equal in modulus, then there exists $X \in GL_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that $|\det A|^{-1/3}X^{-1}AX \in O(3)$ for every $A \in G$. Clearly irreducibility is necessary, because otherwise upper-triangular examples exist.

The above result for *semigroups* in arbitrary dimensions follows from Theorem 2 in "Matrix semigroups with constant spectral radius" by V. Yu. Protasov and A. S. Voynov. I however only need the group case, and I find myself wondering whether this can be dealt with more easily. Unfortunately geometry is quite a weak area for me, my main area of expertise being analysis.  Can anyone help me by suggesting a relatively quick and painless way to prove the above statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because $\det$ is a morphism, as well as $|\det|^{-1/3}$, you may replace $G$ by $H$, which consists of the matrices $|\det A|^{-1/3}A$. This reduces the question to the case where the spectral radius of $A$ equals $1$ for every $A\in G$.

Comment: If it follows from the paper you cite, why don't you just cite that paper? And why do you expect the group case to be easier?

Comment: You can also assume that every element of $G$ has $1$ as an eigenvalue: using Denis Serre's comment if an element $g$  of $G$ has three real eigenvalues, none of which is $1$, all must be $-1$, and the elements of $G$ of determinant $1$ form a normal subgroup of $G$ of index $2$ which is a direct factor of $G$. If $g$ has two non-real eigenvalues, then the other is $\pm 1$ and if it is not $1$, then you can assume  $-I$ to $G$ without affecting the hypotheses, so $G$ is again a direct product of its determinant $1$  matrices and $<-I >$.

Comment: @Anton: firstly it's unpublished, and a published result (or one which I can verify myself) would reassure me of its correctness. Secondly, in general and where possible I would prefer to use an argument which I understand. Thirdly, I hope in the process to learn some methods with which to understand related problems.

Comment: @Anton: I speculate that the group case might be easier than the semigroup case partly just because it is a proper subcase, but also because in the group case one has access to tools like Haar measure and maximal compact subgroups.

Comment: By the other comments, we can assume $\det=1$ and that all eigenvalues are on the unit circle.  This can be formulated as a condition on the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, which depend continuously on the matrix, so it will be harmless to replace $G$ by $\overline{G}$, so we can assume that $G$ is closed.  Now $G$ is subconjugate  to $SO(3)$ iff it is compact (because we can use integration wrt Haar measure to find an invariant inner product).  So the real problem is to prove compactness.

Comment: @friedrichknop I deleted an earlier answer  gave, as it was not complete. I see how to fix it, but I don't want it to be hanged there like that. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @UriBader : If you see how to fix it, you should! It would be useful.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, the proof I see involves taking Zariski closure and getting a group satisfying $\text{tr}(g)=\text{tr}(g^{-1})$. This means in particular that every element has 1 as an ev. I can see that either our group $G$ is compact, or is conjugated into $\text{SO}(2,1)$ which in turn reduces the problem to dim=2. I am not happy with it because I suppose I (or someone else) could come with a simpler proof after some thinking. If it doesn't happen I will write the argument above.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I wrote the proof as promised (even though it is not as simple as I wanted it to be).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific question for $SL(3,\mathbb{R})$ has already been answered by Misha and Uri Bader. I just want to make some additional remarks which say that this holds in greater generality.

Lemma: Suppose $\Gamma \subset GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is a subgroup such that all the eigenvalues of all the elements of $G$ have absolute value $1$. Then there exists a closed subgroup  $G\subset GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ containing $\Gamma $ which contains a unipotent normal subgroup $U$ such that $G/U$ is compact.

Clearly, the eigenvalue of any element of such a $G$ will have absolute value $1$, since the eigenvalue of a  unipotent element is $1$ and elements of a compact group have eigenvalues of absolute value $1$. Hence the above Lemma gives an if and only if condition for $\Gamma $ to have all eigenvalues of absolute value $1$ . (An alternative way to say this is: $\Gamma $ is contained-not necessarily as a closed subgroup- in a closed amenable subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$, which is a unipotent-by- compact extension).

Proof of the lemma:   It is enough to consider the case when $\Gamma$ acts irreducibly on $\mathbb{C}^n$, since the general case follows from this  by looking at a  $\Gamma $ stable  flag in $\mathbb{C}^n$ , where the successive quotients are irreducible. Then the sub-algebra of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ generated by the elements $\gamma \in \Gamma$ is all of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ by Burnside's theorem. The trace form on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is non-degenerate. Fix a basis of $M_n(\mathbb {C})$ of the form $g_i\in \Gamma $ and let $\epsilon _i$ be the dual basis with respect to the trace form. For every $g\in \Gamma $, we have (see Lemma (2.2) of Tits' article on Free Groups in Journal of Algebra  (for a reference see the review

http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=286898 ))

$$ g=\sum trace (gg_i)\epsilon _i.$$ 
All the elements $g\in \Gamma $ have $bounded$ entries since $trace (gg_i)$ - being a sum of eigenvalues of $gg_i$ -  is bounded by the dimension $n$. This proves that $\Gamma $ is contained in a compact subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ if it acts irreducibly on $\mathbb{C} ^n$ and all elements have eigenvalues only of norm $1$.

Now if $\Gamma \subset GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ has the property that the ratio of any two eigenvalues has norm one, then by going to the adjoint representation of $GL(n,\mathbb {C})$ we have:  $Ad(\Gamma )$ is contained in an extension of a compact group by a unipotent group. Hence the same holds for $\Gamma $ as well (up to multiplication by scalars).

Answer (score 8):

The answer by Misha is excellent. Let me however give a more concise and self contained answer, which the OP could use when writing his paper.

First note that the statement is true for $G$ iff it is true for $\{\alpha g\mid g\in G,~\alpha\in \mathbb{R}^*\}$.
Since $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})\to \text{PGL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ is onto, it is enough to prove:

$(*)$ Let $G<\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ be a subgroup such that all eigenvalues of all elements are of absolute value 1. Then $G$ is conjugated to $\text{SO}(3)$.

Note that for $g\in G$ the eigenvalues are $1,\alpha,\bar{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha\in S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$. In particular $\text{tr}(g)=\text{tr}(g^{-1})$.
It follows that $G$ is not Zariski dense. Its Zariski closure must be reductive by the irreducibility assumption, so it is contained in a conjugate of $\text{SO}(3)$ or $\text{SO}(2,1)$ - these are the irreducible reductive subgroups.
We are left to contradict the second possibility.

Recalling that the connected component of $\text{SO}(2,1)$ is isomorphic to $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and by passing to a finite index subgroup of $G$, let me deal now with statement $(*_2)$, the 2-dim analogue of $(*)$.

I will explain why if $G<\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying the conditions above is Zariski dense then it is also dense wrt the usual topology, which will give a contradiction.

Assume $G$ is Zariski dense. Find $g\in G$ of infinite order. Observe that $g$ is not unipotent. Indeed, otherwise a generic conjugate of it $h\in G$ will be another unipotent and the product of high powers $g^nh^m$ will have $\text{tr}>2$ (this becomes clear when you find a basis in which $g,h$ are represented in upper,lower triangular matrix forms). It follows that $g$ is eliptic, hence, up to a choice of basis, $g\in\text{SO}(2)$ is an irrational rotation. It folows that $\text{SO}(2)<\bar{G}$. Since $\text{SO}(2)$ is a maximal subgroup, $\bar{G}=\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: "Since the condition is (real) algebraic (this is not hard to see)": That's actually not true. The set is only semialgebraic. For example a matrix $g\in SL(2,\mathbb R)$ has eigenvalues of modulus 1 if and only if $\text{tr}(g)^2\le4$. The only algebraic condition is that the characteristic polynomial is palindromic (up to some factor) but that is not enough.

Comment: @FriedrichKnop thanks for your correction. I have changed my answer. It should be correct now.

Answer (score 6):

I will consider finitely generated subgroups G  of $SL(3,R)$ as it suffices. Since all eigenvalues are assumed to be on the unit circle you have a dichotomy.

1. The subgroup  G contains an elliptic element of infinite order. Then the subgroup I'd not discrete. Take its topological closure. It is a Lie subgroup of positive dimension. Consider the identity component. By inspection, it is either reducible, and so is your subgroup, or it is irreducible compact, or it contains a subgroup  locally isomorphic to $SL(2,R)$. In the latter case the original group contains an element with an eigenvalue not on the unit circle. If the compact subgroup us irreducible, then G itself is relatively compact. In any case, you are done.
2. All eigenvalues are roots of unity. Since G  is  finitely generated, it contains a finite index subgroup where all elements are unipotent. Thus finite index a subgroup is contained in upper triangular group (up to conjugation). Then you are done again.

**Edit.** Here are some details. Below and above $R={\mathbb R}$ and $C={\mathbb C}$.

Most ingredients of the proof follow closely the proof of the Tits’ alternative as presented in [our book](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/ggt.pdf)) with Drutu, except few things are easier since you are dealing with subgroups of $SL(3,R)$.

First, some terminology: A subgroup $G$ of $SL(n,C)$ is called **distal** if all eigenvalues of all elements of  $G$ have absolute value 1 (such matrices are also called **distal**). An element of $SL(n,C)$ is called **quasiunipotent** if all its eigenvalues are roots of unity.

Here is an elementary lemma that I will use repeatedly:

Lemma 1. If $N< SL(3,R)$ is a nontrivial connected nilpotent Lie subgroup then $N$ either preserves a unique line $L$ or a unique plane $P$ in $R^3$. In particular, if a group $G$ normalizes $N$ then $G$ also preserves that line/plane.

Below, $G< SL(3,R)$ is distal and finitely generated.

Case 1. All its elements of $G$ are quasiunipotent.

One can shorten a bit the next chain of lemmas if one is willing to use Borel’s theorem that every finitely generated subgroup $G$ of $SL(n,R)$ contains a **neat subgroup** $G_0$ of finite index, i.e. a subgroup such that each quasiunipotent element of $G_0$ is unipotent.  Assuming this, we see that if all elements of $G$ are quasiunipotent, then $G$ contains a finite index subgroup $G_1<G$ such that all elements of $G_1$ are unipotent. Hence, by Kolchin’s theorem, $G_0$ is conjugate to the group of upper triangular matrices.

Instead of relying upon Borel and Kolchin's theorems, one can give a direct argument (the proofs are elementary, you can find them in our book for instance):

Lemma 2. If $G< GL(n,C)$ is a finitely generated subgroup such that all elements of $G$ are quasiunipotent then the orders of roots of unity appearing as eigenvalues are uniformly bounded above.

Lemma 3. If $G< GL(n,C)$ is a finitely generated subgroup such that all elements of $G$ are quasiunipotent with  uniformly bounded orders of roots of unity appearing as eigenvalues, then $G$ contains a finite index subgroup $G_1$ which is conjugate to the group of upper triangular matrices. (The proof of this lemma is similar to the proof of Kolchin’s theorem.)

Corollary. If $G< GL(n,C)$ is finitely generated and each element of $G$ is quasiunipotent then $G$ is virtually nilpotent.

Now, if $G< SL(3,R)$ and all its elements are quasiunipotent, then, using Lemma 1, we see that $G$ is either finite or preserves a proper subspace of $R^3$.

Case 2. Suppose that $G< SL(3,R)$ is distal, but some $g\in G$ is not quasiunipotent. By looking at the complex Jordan normal form of such $g$ you see that it has to be diagonal (over ${\mathbb C}$), which means that $g$ is **elliptic**, i.e. is conjugate to a rotation $h\in SO(3)$; and this rotation has infinite order. (Here the argument is simplified by the fact that we have $3\times 3$ matrices.) Therefore, the group $G$ cannot be discrete. Consider its closure $cl(G)$ (in the classical topology) in $SL(3,R)$. Let $H$ denote the identity component of the closure (which has to be a Lie subgroup of positive dimension). The subgroup $H$ is normalized by $G$. Let $N< H$ be the nilpotent radical. Since it is a characteristic subgroup, it is also normalized by $G$. Therefore, by Lemma 1, $G$ preserves a proper subspace in $R^3$.  Thus, assume that $H$ is reductive. Again, by appealing to Lemma 1 we see that $H$ has to be semisimple.

There are not that many semisimple proper connected subgroups in $SL(3,R)$, they are  are $SO(2,1)$ and $SL(2,R)$ and $SO(3)$ (up to conjugation).

If $H\cong SO(3)$ then it preserves a unique inner product on $R^3$, from which it follows that $G$ also preserves the same inner product and, hence, $G$ is relatively compact in this case. Suppose that $H$ is locally isomorphic to $SL(2,R)$ or $SL(3,R)$. By density of $G$ in $H$, it follows that $G$ is not distal, a contradiction.

Lastly, here is how one can handle the case of subgroups $G$ which are not finitely generated. Represent $G$ as a union of finitely generated subgroups $G_i$, $i\in I$.

(a) If the closure of some $G_i$ contains a nontrivial semisimple subgroup $K$, this subgroup has to be compact. Then you can see that the closure of each $G_j$ containing $G_i$ also contains $K$, from which you can see that each $G_j$ preserves the unique $K$-invariant inner product. Hence, $G$ is relatively compact.

(b) Assume that $G$ is not relatively compact. Then there exists $G_i$ which preserves a unique proper subspace $V$ in $R^3$. Since each $G_j$ containing $G_i$ also preserve a unique proper subspace, $V$ has to be invariant under each $G_j$ and, thus, $V$ is $G$-invariant. qed

Last remark: There are examples of finitely generated subgroups $G$ of $SL(n,C)$ such that each element of $G$ is elliptic (conjugate to a unitary matrix) but $G$ itself is not relatively compact. This is something to be aware of.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing a more detailed explanation of this argument.

Comment: @NeilStrickland: As you wish...

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide the simple and beautiful tricky argument by Conze and Guivarch (reference below).

As already observed, we can suppose that $G$ has only elements with eigenvalues of modulus 1. In particular, it has bounded traces. Hence for every $g\in G$, the linear form $L_g:h\mapsto\mathrm{Tr}(gh)$ is bounded on $G$.

Since $G$ acts irreducibly and the dimension $n=3$ is odd, it acts absolutely irreducibly. So it linearly generates the algebra of matrices $\mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbf{R})$. Since $(g,h)\mapsto \mathrm{Tr}(gh)$ is nondegenerate, the functions $L_g$ linearly generate the linear dual $\mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbf{R})^*$, and $L_g(G)$ is bounded for all $g$. Hence $G$ is bounded in $\mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbf{R})$. Since by the distal condition, its closure in $\mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbf{R})$ consists of invertible matrices, we see that its closure is a compact subgroup, which concludes the proof.

---

This is beyond the question, but when the dimension $n$ is even, $G$ might be non-irreducible, but in this case it can be viewed as an irreducible subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_{n/2}(\mathbf{C})$, and the same argument (over the field of complex numbers) shows that it's conjugate into unitary matrices, which means that originally $G$ is conjugate into orthogonal matrices.

---

Reference: J. P. Conze and Y. Guivarc’h *Remarques sur la distalité dans les espaces vectoriels*, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sr. A 278 (1974), 1083-1086.

(Beware that this reference is stated for arbitrary nondiscrete locally compact fields, but has a flaw in the case of positive characteristic. One reference in this generality, but with a less self-contained proof, is in [my book with Pierre de la Harpe](http://www.normalesup.org/~cornulier/MetricLC.pdf), Theorem 4.D.15).